# When should/could I answer my own question?

Tags: discussion, answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I answer my own questions, even those where I knew the answer before asking?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking)

I have a question in stackoverflow  and I've came up with the best (technical) answer in my opinion, is it reasonable for me to post my answer and check it?
It just seems a bit wrong, what do you think I should do? (plus, are there any guidelines about this topic?)

Comment: It feels kind of dirty to me but if it's the best answer and it isn't already represented I would go ahead and do it. Now, if there is an existing answer that got you part of the way there, I'd lean toward rewarding that answer and supplementing it rather than throwing your own answer if it is based largely on the other person's work.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, thanks I'll give the answer poster my answer and ask him if he would add that to his current answer, that way we all make the better of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. It's in the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) and is encouraged if you have an answer to a problem you've been having.

> It’s also OK to ask and answer your own question.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing wrong with posting an answer to your own question, provided it is correct.

The point is to give the best answer not only to the one asking the question (yourself in this case), but to anyone else who ends up reading the question because they have exactly the same issue.

Accepting your own answer is also fine - if it is what helped you most. The fact is, you will not gain **any** reputation from accepting your own answer, in the same way that you cannot upvote your own posts.

Answer (score 2):

If it isn't already represented in part or in full by another answer, and if you weren't pushed most of the way to your solution by an existing answer, then I'd say it's okay to answer your own question.

This is particularly true if you did research outside of the site after posting your question, and came up with a solution superior to the ones already offered.

If an existing answer on your question gave you most of the push toward your solution, I'd rather reward that answer and either edit into the answer the missing part(s) that made your final solution better, or ask the answerer to do so (though this may be difficult if it is additional code or otherwise not convenient to post in a comment).

If, on the other hand, you found your solution in another answer on the same site, I'd be just as tempted to close the question as a duplicate of the other question that contained your solution, if it makes sense (it might not always). Moderators and other answerers are not always aware that your question has a duplicate out there, but IMHO the fewer questions with the exact same answer, the better.